# Neutralino.js - Input event handler not registering

Tags: javascript, neutralinojs

I am trying to detect user key input using javascript. However, the console log seemed to show nothing to which I decided to log the event key instead which didn't log anything either.

Here's a snippet of code from my main.js file:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function onEvent(event) {
    console.log(event.key);
});
```

There are no errors at all, just a blank console. I am using neutralino.js for my project.

The same code seems to work in firefox, with just the index html file and the main javascript file.

Comment: i tried this same code and it worked, are you sure your files are properly loaded?

Comment: Oddly enough, it seems to work now after just copying my html files and the javascript files to some other folder before recreating a new neutralino app and then copying them back. Don't know what happened there.